# Question on Usual Arithmetic Conversions - GCC Compiler

Tags: c, type-conversion, undefined-behavior, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

I'm trying to understand implicit datatype conversions in C. I thought that I had understood this topic, but yet the following code example is still confusing me.

Specifically, I have read about Usual Arithmetic Conversions and Integer Promotion previously from drafts of the C Standard.

```
    unsigned short int a = 0;
    printf("\n%lld", (signed int)a - 1);
```

I am compiling using GCC.

`unsigned short int` is 2 bytes.
`int` is 4 bytes.

When I run this code, I get the following result: ***4294967295***

I expected the result ***-1***.

This is what I expected to happen:

1. Typecast takes precedence, and LHS of `-` becomes `signed int`.
2. `-` operation is carried out. No integer promotion or implicit conversions occur here, as LHS and RHS are already both `signed int`. The result of the operation is -1 with datatype `signed int`.
3. Within `printf` statement, value -1 is retained within the conversion to `long long int`, and -1 is displayed as the result.

Can someone please explain where the flaw in my logic is?

Comment: Use `-Wall` and `-Wextra` when you compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *undefined behaviour* due to `%lld` being the inappropriate format specifier for an `int` type.

Yes indeed `(signed int)a - 1` is an `int` type with value `-1`, but the `printf` call is the undefined part.  There's nothing in the C standard to suggest that a conversion to `long long` occurs.

Comment: Wow, thank you ! Yes, if I typecast `(signed int)a - 1` to `signed long long int`, then I get my expected result.

Answer (score 2):

> Within printf statement, value -1 is retained within the conversion to long long int

There's no such conversion taking place. `printf` (family of functions) is dumb and needs a format string that corresponds to the types of the argument list.

`printf` does *not* work like an ordinary function `void f (long long int x)`, which would have forced an implicit conversion to the type of the parameter ("as per assignment"/"lvalue conversion"). This would have given you the expected "sign extension".

Notably, there's a another kind of specialized implicit conversion going on here called *the default argument promotions*, that only applies to variable argument functions and functions with no prototype.

C17 6.5.2.2/6

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
>   prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that
>   have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument
>   promotions*.

C17 6.5.2.2/7 regarding variable argument functions:

> The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument
>   promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

In practice this means:

- `float` passed to `printf` gets implicitly converted to `double` during function call.
- Small integer types passed to `printf` get implicitly converted during function call as per integer promotions, most likely ending up as `int`.
- Other types passed to `printf` do not get implicitly promoted during the function call.

And then the passed and potentially converted argument gets treated internally as if it was the type specified by the conversion specifier. If that one doesn't match the actual type, the code has undefined behavior.

In your case you pass an `int`, it doesn't get implicitly promoted, but as `printf` treats it as a `long long`, you get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can consider yourself lucky. `a` is a `short int` that undergoes usual arithmetic conversions to a `signed int', even despite the cast, so

```
unsigned short int a = 0;
printf("\n%d", (signed int)a - 1);
```

and

```
unsigned short int a = 0;
printf("\n%d", a - 1);
```

would have the same behaviour, *if* all values of `unsigned short` are representable in `int` (as they are in your case). The result of the conversion is an `int`. Now, for the variable arguments, the default argument promotions are applied and any integers smaller than an `int` is converted to `int` if representable, otherwise `unsigned int`. But `lld` expects a *`signed long long int`* which is 8 bytes wide. Default argument promotions do not promote `int` implicitly to `long long int`.

Now comes the luck part - you did get a *wrong* value. See, since the **behaviour is undefined** you could have gotten the value that you're *expecting*, *this time* - after all it is completely feasible on a 64-bit processor!